# A question about real series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ be two real series, where we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = M >0$. Show that either one of these options happen:

1. Both series converge
2. Both series diverge

I have no clue on how to solve this. Can someone help?

**EDIT**: After the comments, I think this can only be shown true if we assume $a_n >0$ and $b_n>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clue: for $\varepsilon=M/2$ and large enough $n$, $$\frac M2\,b_n\leq a_n\leq \frac{3M}2\,b_n.$$

Comment: Using this you can solve if both $a_n \geq 0$ and $b_n \geq 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, right? In that case I understand how to proceed, but if that doesn't happens does this clue still help?

Comment: You are right, of course. I missed that you were not requiring positive terms in the original question.

Answer (score 4):

This is false: Define

$$a_n= \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/2}},\,\, b_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/2}}+\frac{1}{2n^{3/4}}.$$

Then

$$\frac{a_n}{b_n}= \frac{1}{1+(-1)^n/(2n^{1/4})} \to 1.$$

However $\sum a_n$ converges and $\sum b_n$ diverges.

Comment: Another counter-example: For $n\geq 2$ let $b_n=(-1)^n/\ln n$ and $a_n=b_n+1/n$.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question, you think it's correct now?

Comment: Probably the right assumption is that both $a_n,b_n$ are eventually positive or that  both $a_n,b_n$ are eventually negative.